# mixed fractions have too much space

Tags: support, mathjax

Mixed fractions have too much space, which they don't in other $\TeX$ systems; for instance, `1\frac12` produces $1\frac12$, with the fraction too far away from the integer part.

Comment: A workaround is `\!\frac{1}{2}`: $1\frac12$ vs. $1\!\frac12$. Or even two negative spaces: $1\!\!\frac12$. You can define it as `\def\mixedfrac#1#2{\!\frac{#1}{#2}}` or even `\def\mixedfrac#1#2#3{#1\!\frac{#2}{#3}}`

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be better (or, at least, complementary), to raise this issue with the [MathJax community](http://www.mathjax.org/community/) instead.

Comment: I think this has been mentioned before. Generally, spacing is all messed up in MathJax. I often have to force spacing using \: or \! etc. What's even more irritating is that the behavior changes between versions, e.g. the recent upgrade seriously messed up many of my carefully formatted posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use Arturo's workaround. As Bill Dubuque said, version changes in MathJax can easily make your $\frac12$ end up sitting on top of the $1$. Instead, put the `\frac` in braces or `\mathord`

This is what `$1\frac12$` looks like: $1\frac12$.

This is what `$1{\frac12}$` looks like: $1{\frac12}$.

And this is what `$1\mathord{\frac12}$` looks like: $1\mathord{\frac12}$.

By placing the expression inside braces or using `\mathord`, you are *preventing* the extra space (due to the way MathJax is being slightly less sophisticated about handling fractions: outside of mixed fractions the spacing is generally preferred) from being inserted. This way even if MathJax were to be updated to reflect the usual logic that "fractions after a numeral is to be interpreted as mixed fractions *without* the customary extra space" your expression won't break.

For example:

This is `$1\!{\frac12}$`: $1\!{\frac12}$

And this is with two negative spaces: $1\!\!{\frac12}$.